# Change Color based on user id using javascript in table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a normal html table.My requirement are:

1)The table should be in a white and grey pattern.Say first row should be in white colour and second row should be in grey colour,and third row should be white colour and fourth row should be in white colour.I achieved this by using css.

2)The second requirement is that the pattern should be white and grey alternatively but if any value duplicates then it should show of the same colour as the value. For eg : If 'A' is present in white colour then if it gets repeated then it should again be in white but the next cell should be in grey or vice versa.[sample pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6589c.png)

Im adding my js fiddle -  [js fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/r4cjuapw/)

```
    <body onload="myFunction()">
    <div class="col-lg-12" style="width: 100%; height: 78%;overflow-y: auto;overflow-x: auto;">
    <div class="container" style="width: 100%;">

      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead style="background-color: red;">
    <tr class="bordered">
    <th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th1</b></th>
    <th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th2</b></th>
    <th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th3</b></th>
    <th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th4</b></th>
    <th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th5</b></th>
    <th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th6</b></th>
    <th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th7</b></th>
    <th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th8</b></th>
    <th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th9</b></th>
    <th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th10</b></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
    <tr class="bordered">
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td1 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td2 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td3 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td4 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td5 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td6 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td7 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td8 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td9 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td10 </td>
    </tr>

        </tbody>
        <tbody>
    <tr class="bordered">
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td1 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td2 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td3 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td4 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td5 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td6 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td7 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td8 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td9 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td10 </td>
    </tr>

        </tbody>
        <tbody>
    <tr class="bordered">
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td11 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td12 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td13 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td14 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td15 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td16 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td17 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td18 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td19 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td20 </td>
    </tr>

        </tbody>
            <tbody>
    <tr class="bordered">
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td21 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td22 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td23 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td24 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td25 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td26 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td27 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td28 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td29 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td30 </td>
    </tr>

        </tbody>
                <tbody>
    <tr class="bordered">
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td21 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td22 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td23 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td24 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td25 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td26 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td27 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td28 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td29 </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td30 </td>
    </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      </div>
      </body>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
tbody:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
<script>
function myFunction(){
  alert("hai");
  for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName('tbody').length;i++){
    for( var j=i+1;j<document.getElementsByTagName('tbody').length;j++){
      if(document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[i].children[0].children[0].innerText == 
        document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[j].children[0].children[0].innerText){
        document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[i].classList.add('parent');
       document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[j].classList.add('parent');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate over the `tbody`'s and remember the shade you associate to each text entry when you encounter the entry the first time. So when you encounter an entry, you first verify if it was previously encountered, if so, get its shade from the map, otherwise, toggle the shade and add the entry in your map.

Since your two requirements are slightly in opposition, you have to remove the CSS that makes the alternating pattern and instead use a class for the shades.

Here I only use a single class for the dark shade and add it to the dark rows while iterating over the `tbody`'s.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const isDark = { };
  let shade = false;

  Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')).forEach(body => {
    const text = body.children[0].children[0].innerText;
    if (!(text in isDark)) {
      isDark[text] = shade;
      shade = !shade;
    }
    if (isDark[text]) body.classList.add('dark');
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
.dark {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
<div class="col-lg-12" style="width: 100%; height: 78%;overflow-y: auto;overflow-x: auto;">
<div class="container" style="width: 100%;">

  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead style="background-color: red;">
<tr class="bordered">
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th1</b></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th2</b></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th3</b></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th4</b></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th5</b></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th6</b></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th7</b></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th8</b></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th9</b></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#a9a9a9" style="font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;text-align:center;"><b>th10</b></th>
</tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
<tr class="bordered">
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td1 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td2 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td3 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td4 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td5 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td6 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td7 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td8 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td9 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td10 </td>
</tr>

    </tbody>
    <tbody>
<tr class="bordered">
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td1 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td2 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td3 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td4 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td5 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td6 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td7 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td8 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td9 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td10 </td>
</tr>

    </tbody>
    <tbody>
<tr class="bordered">
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td11 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td12 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td13 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td14 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td15 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td16 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td17 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td18 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td19 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td20 </td>
</tr>

    </tbody>
        <tbody>
<tr class="bordered">
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td21 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td22 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td23 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td24 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td25 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td26 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td27 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td28 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td29 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td30 </td>
</tr>

    </tbody>
            <tbody>
<tr class="bordered">
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td21 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td22 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td23 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td24 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td25 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td26 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td27 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td28 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td29 </td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size: 17px;font-family: monospace;padding-top:2%;">td30 </td>
</tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

**If you want to merge the duplicate labels**, then you have to group your rows in the same `<tbody>` tag, at least the rows to be merged, this will allow you to remove the duplicates and add a `rowspan=X` on the first label. Here is a snippet to show this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const firstRows = { };
  let shade = false;
  
  const colsToMerge = [0, 1];

  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')).forEach(tr => {
    const text = tr.children[0].innerText;
    if (!(text in firstRows)) {
      firstRows[text] = { shade, elem: tr, count: 1 };
      shade = !shade;
    } else {
      const firstRow = firstRows[text]
      firstRow.count++;
      colsToMerge.forEach(i => tr.children[i].remove());
      colsToMerge.forEach(i =>
        firstRow.elem.children[i]
                .setAttribute('rowspan', firstRow.count)
      );
    }
    if (firstRows[text].shade) tr.classList.add('dark');
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th {
  background: #a9a9a9;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.dark {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><b>th1</b></th>
                <th><b>th2</b></th>
                <th><b>th3</b></th>
                <th><b>th4</b></th>
                <th><b>th5</b></th>
                <th><b>th6</b></th>
                <th><b>th7</b></th>
                <th><b>th8</b></th>
                <th><b>th9</b></th>
                <th><b>th10</b></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>td1 </td>
                <td>td2 </td>
                <td>td3 </td>
                <td>td4 </td>
                <td>td5 </td>
                <td>td6 </td>
                <td>td7 </td>
                <td>td8 </td>
                <td>td9 </td>
                <td>td10 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>td1 </td>
                <td>td2 </td>
                <td>td3 </td>
                <td>td4 </td>
                <td>td5 </td>
                <td>td6 </td>
                <td>td7 </td>
                <td>td8 </td>
                <td>td9 </td>
                <td>td10 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>td11 </td>
                <td>td12 </td>
                <td>td13 </td>
                <td>td14 </td>
                <td>td15 </td>
                <td>td16 </td>
                <td>td17 </td>
                <td>td18 </td>
                <td>td19 </td>
                <td>td20 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>td21 </td>
                <td>td22 </td>
                <td>td23 </td>
                <td>td24 </td>
                <td>td25 </td>
                <td>td26 </td>
                <td>td27 </td>
                <td>td28 </td>
                <td>td29 </td>
                <td>td30 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>td21 </td>
                <td>td22 </td>
                <td>td23 </td>
                <td>td24 </td>
                <td>td25 </td>
                <td>td26 </td>
                <td>td27 </td>
                <td>td28 </td>
                <td>td29 </td>
                <td>td30 </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: jo_va is there any possibility to merge the duplicate value for one column,For eg:the first two rows first column should be merged.

Comment: @Thirshal, yes this is possible, you would have to iterate a second time though, because you would need to set "rowspan=X" where is is the number of duplicates. So the first iteration you would count the duplicates, and the second one set rowspan on the first one and then remove the following duplicates, I will try to add a snippet to my answer to show you

Comment: Oh, no I realized you are using a tbody for each row, so this is impossible. But without the tbody (a single one around everything) it would be possible to merge successive row labels in a single cell

Comment: jo_va i got it what you are saying.can we merge with the single tbody.

Comment: @Thirshal, I will add a snippet to my answer for that yes

Comment: @Thirshal, I didn't have to iterate twice as I thought, you just have to reset the rowspan every time you find a label with the same name You also have to use querySelectorAll to get the `tr` inside the `tbody` and not inside the `thead`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for that jo_va ,i have an two doubt ,1) To do this, we want to order by the entire table??2)Here we have merged values for first column,if we want to do the same thing in the next two column.Say,first th1 column is alone merged,second th2 column alone should merged..

Comment: Thanks for the help.you saved by day.

Comment: hi, I am having a problem in merging table row, in the above code snippet while merging some values are missing. The first two rows values are the same while merging, the values next to it are missing, and the same value is repeated again. For eg: In the first two rows,td1 and td2 are merged and if we come to the next column again td2 is repeating and td3 value is missing.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName('tbody').length;i++){

  if(document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[i].children[0].children[0].innerText == 
    document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[i].children[0].children[0].innerText){
    document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[i].classList.add('parent');
   for color change
  }
}
```